# Can't case Firestore document to List<Map<String, dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

On firestore, I have the following document:

```html
[
  {
    id: 1,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    quantity: 3
  },
]
```

I'm trying to read the date and cast it to `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` so that I may use my `fromMap()` method to convert it to a list of `Item`:

```html
class Item()
{
  const Item(this.id, this.quantity);
  
  final String id;
  final int quantity;
  
  factory Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Item(
        id: map['id'] as String,
        quantity: map['quantity'] as int,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The thing is, when my firestore document is a `Map` (that is, a plain object, and not an array), my `fromMap` works just fine, but when it is an array of objects, dart treats the array as `List<Object?>` and not `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` like it should.

Any ideas how I can convert an array with objects to a list of instances of some class?